# Fastest Change detection - Multithreaded GET request to JSON endpoint

Tags: ruby, multithreading, performance, web-scraping

I’m working on a research project that requires us to react to changes in the response of a JSON endpoint as soon as they happen. 
Right now I’m spawning a number of threads that continuously issue requests to that endpoint. I’m not sure if this is providing us with the best performance. I’m also not sure how to settle on the number of threads I should spawn (so that I react to changes as soon as they happen - changes happen at unpredictable times and rates).

I’m doing this in ruby:

```
    require 'oj'
    require 'typhoeus'

    threads = []

    mutex = Mutex.new

    (0..50).each do |i|
      threads << Thread.new do 
        while true
          begin
            url = "http://target-endpoint.com/json"; 
            response = Typhoeus.get(url, followlocation: true)

            if response.code == 200
              orders = Oj.load(response.response_body)

              mutex.synchronize do 
                # analyze response, act accordingly
              end 
            end

          rescue StandardError => e
            puts e.message
            puts e.backtrace
          end
        end 
      end 
    end 

    threads.each(&:join)
```

This code is running on ubuntu 16.04 on an AWS r3.xlarge instance ( 4 vCPUs, 30.5GB of memory). I’m also not sure what the bottleneck would be here (CPU or memory). 
We have authorization to put a heavy load on the server we are interacting with. That server also uses cloudflare.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wonder if a JSON API is fast enough to justify multiple threads because your bottleneck would be the network latency and the server response time. I would expect one thread in a loop or one request per second to be fast enough considering that a JSON API is very slow in the context of a real-time experience anyway. Did you consider changing the API to something that is able to serve requests faster (perhaps sockets or push notifications)?

Comment: The server can take a significant time to respond sometimes (e.g. 5 seconds). I have no control over the server unfortunately, and after talking to the folks that manage it, they are not willing to change it.

Comment: Are the folks managing the API okay with running multiple threads against it? Do they have a recommendation about how many requests per timeframe are suitable or when a client will be blocked? IMHO it is ridiculous to run 50 threads in a loop again an API endpoint that takes 5 seconds to answer - I would call that a DOS attempt.

Comment: I would just benchmark it. Time your multithreaded version against a single threaded one that just loops. I suspect you won't see any benefit from the multithreaded one because the other server seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @spickermann, the owners of the server know we are doing this. They are ok with it. They haven't given us any recommendations on how to go about it.